# mysql stored procedure update query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure, but I'm having trouble getting it to create thus work.  I know my sql code is working since I have tested it, but I don't know why I can't get it to work.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (
select AVG(Score) as aScore, MovieCode
from UserMovies
group by MovieCode
)

UPDATE Movies
set Score =(
select aScore
from table2
where Movies.Code=table2.MovieCode )

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2
```

It won't let me create the stored procedure.  Says error near the update part of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually something like this should work:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_Name`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Name`()
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2 AS (
  select AVG(Score) as aScore, MovieCode
  from UserMovies
  group by MovieCode
  );

  UPDATE Movies
  set Score = (
  select aScore
  from table2
  where Movies.Code=table2.MovieCode );

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae47e/1)</kbd>

Comment: I tried the begin and end and even the ; at the end and it didn't work, but if copied and past the sql part of the temp table, update, and drop it works.  Why?  The only difference I really see is a space between = and ( on the update section.  Was that really the issue?

Comment: @billbob: You use something like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: I know this is an additional question, but when calling a procedure does it usually not report on rows affected.  Got the procedure created and it works just doesn't show any update in the result window.  Had to go to the table to see that it worked.

Comment: @billbob: You can use [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) to get what you need within the stored procedure.